# Elixir: File upload to a REST API with json data

Tags: api, rest, file-upload, multipartform-data, elixir

I'm trying to upload a file to a rest api using HTTPoison.

I can get a file upload to work with the following code, but I need to replace `{"name", "value"}` with a json payload or find a way to have json/nested data be sent with same request.

```
url = 'https://sandbox.e-signlive.com/api/packages/dc337476-9841-454a-b5d4-fe5a2b60136d/documents'

headers = [{"Authorization", "secret_key"}]

HTTPoison.post!("httpbin.org/post", {:multipart, [{"name", "value"}, {:file, "/Path/to/document.pdf"}]}, headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems enctype is missing:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```